Ubuntu Server Stuck After Reboot: /dev/sda2: clean, ... Error and "Error Reading the CPU Table" in Recovery Mode
I'm having an issue with my Ubuntu server (running on a Dell PowerEdge T640). After initiating a reboot, the server doesn't fully restart and gets stuck at the following message:
/dev/sda2: clean, 405390/14623808 files, 15390903/58484930 blocks
I've tried rebooting multiple times, but the system hangs at this point without continuing.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
I managed to boot into recovery mode, and when I run dpkg from there, I get the following error message:
Error reading the CPU table in Ubuntu
I’ve checked for disk issues, and the file system seems clean, as indicated by the /dev/sda2: clean message.
I’ve also checked the boot sequence and tried accessing the GRUB menu, but I can’t seem to interact with it during the boot process.
Has anyone encountered this problem before, or does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this issue? I’m not sure if it’s related to the CPU error or something else.
Any help would be appreciated!
Server model: Dell PowerEdge T640
OS: Ubuntu Server
Filesystem: ext4 on /dev/sda2
Issue: Stuck during boot after the /dev/sda2: clean message, unable to complete the reboot
Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Take a look at the answers @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417666/q-e-error-reading-the-cpu-table-in-ubuntu
